# How to dynamically populate MediaItem from firestore in audio_service?

Tags: just-audio

I have been trying to dynamically populate MediaItem with some audio data from firestore.

I am using the exact plugin example, but this time mediaItems is being sourced dynamically from firestore. I have reviewed my code multiple times, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here are my attempts:

First I fetched the song data using a StreamBuilder and passed it as a DocumentSnapshot List to the AudioServicePlayer() page.

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> _list;
_list = snapshot.data.docs;

Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => JustAudioPlaylist(
                                songs: [_list[index]],
                                
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                      child:
                          Container(child: Center(child: Text('My Playlists'))),
                    );
                  }),
            )
```

I successfully received the QueryDocumentSnapshot as expected. But when I tried to populate MediaItem with widget.songs List, it returns just a blank white page with no error. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here;

```
class AudioServicePlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'audio-service';
  List<DocumentSnapshot> songs = [];
  AudioServicePlayer({this.songs});

  @override
  _AudioServicePlayerState createState() => _AudioServicePlayerState();
}

class _AudioServicePlayerState extends State<AudioServicePlayer> {
  MediaLibrary _mediaLibrary = MediaLibrary();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _mediaLibrary._items.addAll(widget.songs
        .map((song) => MediaItem(
              // This can be any unique id, but we use the audio URL for convenience.
              id: song['song'],
              album: "Science Friday",
              title: song['songTitle'],
              artist: song['artist']['artistName'],
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
              artUri: Uri.parse(song['songImage']).toString(),
            ))
        .toList());
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `widget.songs` is an empty list? That would explain the empty screen. Of course if that's the case you'd then want to know why `widget.songs` is empty but you haven't shown the code that passes in this parameter so there's not enough information to answer that.

Comment: @RyanHeise thank you for your kind help. Now, I understand better.